# MySQL Workbench export of net structured values from db using sql query

Tags: mysql, tree, mysql-workbench, export-to-csv

I have two linked lists in mySQLWorkbench. One is product_group and one is parent_product_group. Each one have a uniqueID in form of a random string (BLOB).
The whole datastructure behind it can be viewed as some sort of a tree (or more a net).
So e.g. productgroup C and D have the parent B and B has the parent A.

What I'm trying to do is to export that data from mySQLWorkbench, so the data structure can be seen in excel as it is.
To give you an example of what it is supposed to look like, I have attached a screenshot.

Thank you for your help
Florian
[image: Datastructure]

[image: product_group structure]